# If an UPDATE finds multiple values why does it not fail?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If you update using an alias with a FROM statement and a JOIN used in the FROM statement means there will be multiple possible values for the SET operation then why does SQL Server allow the UPDATE to happen? It seems to pick the top value from the set of possible ones but this can't be a consistent approach so why does the statement not fail instead?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Updated (ID_Unq INT, Value CHAR(1));

CREATE TABLE #UpdateFrom (ID_Non_Unq INT, Value CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO #Updated (ID_Unq, Value) VALUES
(1,'A'),
(2,'B'),
(3,'C');

INSERT INTO #UpdateFrom (ID_Non_Unq, Value) VALUES
(1,'A'),
(1,'B'),
(2,'C'),
(2,'D'),
(3,'E'),
(3,'F');

SELECT *
FROM #Updated a
JOIN #UpdateFrom b ON a.ID_Unq = b.ID_Non_Unq;

UPDATE a
SET Value = b.Value
FROM #Updated a
JOIN #UpdateFrom b ON a.ID_Unq = b.ID_Non_Unq;

SELECT * FROM #Updated;
```

Comment: I see what you are saying -  the UPDATE statement appears to only apply one operation to a given row from the JOIN operation. If you add an OUTPUT clause to the UPDATE then you see only 3 rows are updated. This differs from the SELECT which will show 6 rows from the join. I suspect this is SQL Server trying to make best sense of what you are asking it to do and so rather than appling 2 updates to each row it simply 'shortcuts' to operation and applies the first JOIN result for a given row in the table being updated.

Comment: It may well be for performance reasons. Updating using the first record found would be quicker than checking whether there are multiple values before performing the update. This is just a guess though.

Comment: Adding 'OUTPUT 'UPDATE: ID_Unq=' + CAST(INSERTED.ID_Unq as varchar(10))+' '+ DELETED.Value+'=>'+INSERTED.Value' below the SET Value=.. statement will show the updates which are applied, which perhaps makes it clearer what is going on

Comment: Can't answer *why*, but I can point out that it is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177523.aspx): "Use caution when specifying the FROM clause to provide the criteria for the update operation. The results of an UPDATE statement are undefined if the statement includes a FROM clause that is not specified in such a way that only one value is available for each column occurrence that is updated, that is if the UPDATE statement is not deterministic." Given that it's a non-standard extension to `UPDATE`, it may just be "legacy reasons"

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen - "without indexes/keys which enforce a selection order" - there are no such things. The *only* thing that enforces a selection order is an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: yeah  you're right, I know and  was too hasty in my comment. Thanks for correcting :) I've removed my comment, because I cannot edit it.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments, that documentation link does help clarify the why for me. Would an ORDER BY in the FROM section of the query set the UPDATE to pick the value in a standard way? In the system I found this from we had a MERGE which had failed due to the duplication and an UPDATE which did almost the same thing and had not failed which is why I was curious as to why this behaviour happens.

Comment: Why do you want to trick it into **some** standard way?  If there is more than one value then write the update to use the proper value.

Comment: I don't want to trick the update, I understand this is not the best way. I am simply trying to learn more of how SQL Server works.

Answer (score 1):

SQL will allow many nondeterministic operations
In absence of an order by clause the order returned may change
First (and last) row processed may change

Rather than let SQL guess perform an update that only returns a single value

e.g.

```
UPDATE a 
SET Value = max(b.Value) 
FROM #Updated a  
JOIN #UpdateFrom b ON a.ID_Unq = b.ID_Non_Unq   
GROUP BY a.Value;
```